How to mask \begin and \end in the versions package?
With the versions package, a version switch foo can be created to turn on/off the text that is written within the foo environment. My goal is to create new commands \mybegin and \myend, which mask the calls to \begin{foo} and \end{foo}.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{versions}

\newcommand{\mybegin}{\begin{foo}}
\newcommand{\myend}{\end{foo}}
 
\excludeversion{foo}

\begin{document}

Nothing to see here.
\mybegin
Surprise!
\myend

\end{document}

However, this fails with the error
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 16. <inserted text>\fi<>

The reason seems to be, that \excludeversion starts an \iffalse in \foo and redefines \end{foo} to produce a \fi. Now I suppose that macro expansion leads to an \iffalse without a \fi when expanding \mybegin. However, I don't know how to prevent this from happening.

For context: In the end I try to mirror the behavior of \processifversion, which produces the original text if no version foo was defined (i.e. no \includeversion or \excludeversion are present). In my use case I can't use \processifversion as this does not allow for listings in the argument. My final goal is to produce something like this:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mybegin}{
 \@ifundefined{foo}{\relax}{\begin{foo}}
}
\newcommand{\myend}{
 \@ifundefined{foo}{\relax}{\end{foo}}
}
\makeatother


like verbatim, once you turn off normal processing, the system needs to look ahead for a literal \end{foo} as no expansion is happening so any definition attached to the end code will not execute.  Hiding environment syntax behind commands is always a bad idea: it works in some simple cases but in general it does not work.

@DavidCarlisle
While this is certainly true, I am not aiming to write generalizable code, but to solve a quite specific problem in a (more or less) controlled environment. Do you have an idea what to do instead?

you would have to copy the code for verbatim but modify its internals to look for \myend instead of \end{verbatim}
